# Grouped times series lag on selected variables using dplyr

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr to lag some variables (all of which have a common naming convention) for each group in my data set.

I thought `mutate_if` would work, but I get an error (below). `mutate_each` works, but for all columns rather than the select few.

For example, I were looking to lag only the Sepal measurements:

```
iris %>% 
  tbl_df() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  slice(1:3) %>%
  # mutate_each(funs(lag(.)))
  mutate_if(contains("Sepal"), funs(lag(.)))
#> Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :  object 'p' of mode 'function' was not found
```

to get a final data set like:

```
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>     <fctr>
# 1           NA          NA          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 2          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 3          4.9         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa
# 4           NA          NA          4.7         1.4 versicolor
# 5          7.0         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
# 6          6.4         3.2          4.9         1.5 versicolor
# 7           NA          NA          6.0         2.5  virginica
# 8          6.3         3.3          5.1         1.9  virginica
# 9          5.8         2.7          5.9         2.1  virginica
```

Comment: `contains` returns an index of the columns that match the string, not a logical vector.  `mutate_if` relies on a using predicate functions that return logical vectors, which is why the `grepl` answer from @Sotos works.  Using `mutate_at` instead with `contains` should work.

Comment: @aosmith I added your explanation to my answer

Comment: Following up on @aosmith, should you use `mutate_at()`, make sure you use the `vars()` helper: `mutate_at(vars(contains('Sepal')), lag)`. Also, should you want to use `mutate_each()`, you could do:  `mutate_each(funs(lag), contains('Sepal'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work,

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
     tbl_df() %>%
     group_by(Species) %>%
     slice(1:3) %>%
     mutate_if(grepl('Sepal', names(.)), funs(lag(.)))
```

As @aosmith explains, `contains` returns an index of the columns that match the string, whereas `mutate_if` relies on a using predicate functions that return logical vectors, which is why the `grepl` option works.

In addition, as @StevenBeaupre mentions,

```
iris %>% 
     tbl_df() %>%
     group_by(Species) %>%
     slice(1:3) %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(contains('Sepal')), lag)
```

Comment: Maybe include the more idiomatic: `mutate_at(vars(contains('Sepal')), lag)`